# Implicit conversion without assignment?

Tags: c#, casting, implicit

**Preserved question - see Edit at the bottom**
I'm working on a small functional library, basically to provide some readability by hiding basic cyclomatic complexities.  The provider is called `Select<T>` (with a helper factory called `Select`), and usage is similar to

```
public Guid? GetPropertyId(...)
{
    return Select
        .Either(TryToGetTheId(...))
        .Or(TrySomethingElseToGetTheId(...))
        .Or(IGuessWeCanTryThisTooIfWeReallyHaveTo(...))
        //etc.
        ;
}
```

and the library will take care of the short circuiting, etc.  I also added an implicit conversion from `Select<T>` to `T`, so I can write

```
public Guid GetPropertyId(...)
{
    ServiceResult result = Select
        .Either(TryToGetTheId(...))
        .Or(TrySomethingElseToGetTheId(...));

    return result.Id;
}
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is an implicit conversion to T without assignment:

```
public Guid GetPropertyId(...)
{
    return 
        //This is the part that I want to be implicitly cast to a ServiceResult
        Select
        .Either(TryToGetTheId(...))
        .Or(TrySomethingElseToGetTheId(...))
        //Then I want to access this property on the result of the cast
        .Id;
}
```

However, the specified syntax doesn't work - I have to either assign it to a variable, or explicitly cast it.  Is there a way to get an implicit cast inline?

**EDIT**

What I want to do is this:

```
class Foo { 
    public int Fuh { get; set; } 
}

class Bar {
    private Foo _foo;
    public static implicit operator Foo (Bar bar)
    {
        return bar._foo;
    }
}

//What I have to do
Foo bar = GetABar();
DoSomethingWith(bar.Fuh);

//What I want to do
DoSomethingWith(GetABar().Fuh);
```

Comment: Observations: "hiding" cyclomatic complexity makes the numbers better, but doesn't necessarily simplify your programming (or debugging). Also, your 3rd code block has bad English grammar ("either a or b c") so if you're going for the "fluent" style (which I personally find condescending), you're better off with .Or(value) at the end anyway.

Comment: @abhishek - the type of Id in this case is Guid

Comment: What's the signature of the `Either` and `Or` methods? And what is the purpose of this? Why not simply use shortcut evaluation like `TryToGetTheId(...) || TrySomethingElse() || GuessWeCanTryThisToo()`?

Comment: @Mark - I understand those points.  The "grammar" is supposed to be (either a or b).c, but .Or(default) makes an appreciable improvement in my opinion.  However, without an affirmative answer to this question, I can't even add the .Or(default)

Comment: There's got to be something you're not posting. Perhaps the `Id` property is actually `Guid?` but you're trying to return it from a function whose return type is just `Guid`.

Comment: @Gabe - I'm not worried about a cast out of the GetPropertyId method, but *inside* of it.  I've edited the post to (hopefully) clarify.

Comment: @0xA3 - The Method signatures for Either and Or are just Select<T> Either(T value) and Select<T> Or(T value).  The purpose of these operations is basically to provide a fluent interface around what would otherwise be a string of coalescence operators.  I've also built some more useful functionality that's not relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Gabe is right - there is something you are not telling us; a "return" automatically does an implicit conversion to the return type. It would help greatly if you'd provide a few details like **what is the error message?**. Even better, provide a simple, short repro that demonstrates the problem that we can actually compile and analyze rather than guessing what your code looks like.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - This does seem to have caused a lot of confusion.  I'll update the question.

Comment: So the problem is actually that the member access operator looks up Fuh on Bar, when you want it to look up on Foo, because there is an implicit conversion from Bar to Foo?  Member access doesn't work like that. The member access operator *accesses members*, hence its name. **Just because Bar goes to Foo does not add the members of Bar to Foo.**

Comment: I realize that Bar does not gain the members of Foo, even when the conversion is defined.  My question is whether there is a way to tell the compiler to check against both the members of Bar and a class to which it is implicitly convertible without doing an assignment to a specific type.

Comment: You could do a typecast.  I forget the C# syntax, but perhaps DoSomethingWith(((foo)GetABar()).Fuh);

Comment: That's the correct syntax, but explicit casting is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @arootbeer: you seem to want two contradictory things. You want a way to hint to the compiler that the lookup should be on type Foo. *That is precisely what the cast is*. A cast is a hint to the compiler that says "hey, compiler, use this type instead of that one, I know what I'm doing." And yet you reject that solution. What do you really want here?

Comment: What I'm looking for is syntactic sugar - that's it.  I'm aware that there are several ways to explicitly do what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's true that an implicit cast won't work here, you could possibly do better than an explicit cast by adding a `Value` property to `Select<T>`. Then your expression would be `Select.[operations].Value.Id`, which still reads reasonably well.

Comment: I ended up calling the property Result, but it's the same thing.  I was hoping for a compiler hint, like supercat mentioned below, but this is apparently the best I'm gonna get.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: when using the member access ("dot") operator, is there a way to tell the compiler to look up both the members of Bar and a type to which Bar is implicitly convertible?

Yes, there are two ways to do that.

The first is called "inheritance". You do it like this:

```
class Bar : Blah { ... }
...
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.Whatever();  // member access will look up members of both Bar and Blah.
Blah blah = bar; // bar is implicitly convertible to Blah.
```

That tells the compiler "when you're looking up members of Bar, look up members of Blah too".  It also tells the compiler that instances of Bar are implicitly convertible to type Blah.

Blah can be either a class or an interface type.

The second is called "class and interface constraints on type parameters". You hint to the compiler like this:

```
void M<T>(T t) where T : Blah
{
    t.Whatever(); // member access looks up members of Blah on t
    Blah blah = t; // t is implicitly convertible to Blah
```

Now t is implicitly convertible to Blah, and member access on t will include members declared on Blah.

Again, Blah can be an interface or class type.

There are no other ways in C# to affect member lookup on a type Bar such that the added members are declared on a type Blah, where Bar is implicitly convertible to Blah.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  It would be nice in this case if the implicit cast operator would enable you to use Foo as Bar, but I can certainly see the complexities involved with that (especially as default behavior).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is doable; some kind of operator has to come into play to cause the casting.  The compiler/runtime can't just 'know' that you want it to be of type T, you have to somehow instruct it to do so.

Comment: That's the answer I'm expecting to be correct at the end of the day.  However, I figured I'd put the question out there in case I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

If you want put the conversion to guid inline you can do a extension method

```
public static Guid ToGuid(this string id)
{
    return new Guid(id);
}

public Guid GetPropertyId(...)
{
    return Select
        .Either(TryToGetTheId(...))
        .Or(TrySomethingElseToGetTheId(...))
        .Id
        .ToGuid();
}
```

i don't think it really add something, but in my pov is better to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your problem. `Or` returns a `Select`, not a `ServiceResult`, so there's no way that the compiler could know that you expect to get the `Id` property from a `ServiceResult` object. How could it? Should it see that there is no `Select.Id` property and start looking for possible implicit conversions to see if one of them has a property called `Id`?

Here are a few of your choices:

```
public Guid GetPropertyId(...) 
{ 
    return  ((ServiceResult)
        Select 
        .Either(TryToGetTheId(...)) 
        .Or(TrySomethingElseToGetTheId(...)))
        .Id; 
}
```

or

```
class Select
{
    public ServiceResult AsServiceResult()
    {
        return (ServiceResult)this;
    }
}

public Guid GetPropertyId(...) 
{ 
    return  
        Select 
        .Either(TryToGetTheId(...)) 
        .Or(TrySomethingElseToGetTheId(...)) 
        .AsServiceResult()
        .Id; 
}
```

or

```
class Select
{
    public Guid Id { get { return ((ServiceResult)this).Id; } }
}

public Guid GetPropertyId(...) 
{ 
    return  
        Select 
        .Either(TryToGetTheId(...)) 
        .Or(TrySomethingElseToGetTheId(...)) 
        .Id; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
public Guid GetPropertyId(...)
{
    return new Guid(Select
        .Either(TryToGetTheId(...))
        .Or(TrySomethingElseToGetTheId(...))
        .Id);
}
```

Comment: That would technically work, but why allocate a new instance of a Guid, just to avoid a cast?

Comment: This syntax doesn't work either - you still have to cast the result of the method chain to something.  It's actually exactly the same as my last statement, but with the results sent to a Guid constructor.

Comment: I think in his example, it's actually a Nullable<Guid>, so you have to actually return the Value member to get the _real_ Guid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to be dealing with specific types, you could add wrapper methods or properties.  If myThing has a method of type "Bar" which returns "self.internalThing.Bar", then one could maintain the illusion that that an expression returning a myThing was really returning an expression of its wrapped type.  I know of no way to do that in the general case, however.  It might be useful for future C# and VB versions to allow one property in a class to be "wrapped", but I know of no way to do that in the language as it exists.

Comment: VB6 had "default properties" that operated this way, but it was terribly inconvenient as it meant that you had to constantly decide whether you wanted the default property (`let`) or the actual object (`set`).

Comment: @Gabe: The VB6 default properties weren't related to wrapping, I don't think (though maybe they could be used for that).  If object foo's class had default property bar, the statement "foo = boz" was equivalent to "foo.bar = boz".  What I'd like would be to declare that foo's class "wraps" bar, such that if bar supports field/property/method zaq, but foo does not, then saying foo.zig would be translated as foo.bar.zig.  I don't think making bar a default property of foo in vb6 would do that; even if it did, the other costs would be annoying.

Comment: supercat: Sorry, I was a bit confused by your post. It sounds like you're talking about interface delegation (like described here: http://beust.com/java-delegation.html) in which case it would be a nice feature to add to the language.

Comment: @Gabe: That's basically what I was thinking of, though I'd have been inclined to only allow a single delegation to avoid naming conflicts.  I suppose if one only delegated to interfaces, the conflicts might not be so bad since interfaces can't change without a recompile.  It might be useful to delegate to a class, though, and that would only be safe if it was the sole delegation; if one might want to delegate inherited methods of a class, one should make the delegating class be a generic class with the wrapped class as a type parameter.

Comment: @supercat: re *"declare that foo's class "wraps" bar, ..."* - seems to me that defining a common *interface* with the desired methods is the clean way to do this. A bit of work in defining `foo`, to forward the interface members, but calling sites are simple. (Basically what you say in your answer, but I'm pointing out that making the wrapper methods part of an *interface* declaration may be helpful to callers. Then either a `bar` or a `foo` can be provided, and it works, if they both have that interface.)