# implicit operator on generic types

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

Is there anything wrong with using an implicit operator like the following:

```
//linqpad c# program example
void Main()
{
    var testObject = new MyClass<int>() { Value = 1 };

    var add = 10 + testObject; //implicit conversion to int here
    add.Dump(); // 11
}

class MyClass<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator T (MyClass<T> myClassToConvert)
    {
        return myClassToConvert.Value;
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could treat as instance of the object as a value type this way, but seeing as I've never seen an example of this I thought maybe there was a reason *not* to do something like this that someone could point out?

In my actual code I was thinking of doing this as part of a data abstraction layer, so that I could return objects with information describing the underlying data, but allow the logic code to treat it as a value type when all it needs to know about is the value, and at the same time keep it all nice and type safe with the generics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all of the following are true:

- *all* possible values of your `MyClass<T>` type (including `null` if it’s not a value type!) map to a valid value of `T`
- the implicit operator never throws (not even for `null`!)
- the implicit conversion makes semantic sense and is not confusing to the client programmer

then there is nothing wrong with this. Of course you *could* do any of these three things, but it would be bad design. In particular, an implicit operator that throws can be very hard to debug because the place where it is called doesn’t say that it is being called.

For example, consider that `T?` has no implicit conversion to `T` (where `T` is, of course, a value type). If there was such an implicit operator, it would have to throw when the `T?` is null, as there is no obvious value to convert `null` to that would make sense for *any* value type `T`.

---

Let me give an example where I had trouble debugging an issue where the implicit operator threw:

```
public string Foo()
{
    return some_condition ? GetSomething() : null;
}
```

Here, `GetSomething` returned something of a type I wrote which has a user-defined implicit conversion to `string`. I made *absolutely sure* that `GetSomething` could never return `null`, and yet I got a `NullReferenceException`! Why? Because the above code is **not** equivalent to

```
return some_condition ? (string)GetSomething() : (string)null;
```

but to

```
return (string)(some_condition ? GetSomething() : (Something)null);
```

Now you can see where the `null` came from!

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the concern around nullable types... It seems to me that if you had n = new MyClass<int?>(){Value=null}; and the consuming code attempted to do something like int i=n; and it would throw the same exception that any bad cast would, nothing special about the nullable type here right?

Comment: @asawyer: It was just an example. Imagine there was no `T?` and *you* had to implement a `Nullable<T>` of your own. Would you give it an implicit conversion to `T`? My answer explains why you shouldn’t, and why the *real* `T?` doesn’t.

Comment: I see now, it's these types of concerns that prompted the question in the first place.  It looks like I should be ok to procede, but be very cautious.

Answer (score 1):

That's a great pattern.  Just keep in mind that in order to use it as a variable of type `T`, you have to either explicitly cast it to `T`, or assign it to a variable of type `T`.  The cast will take place automatically in method calls and other things (such as your addition example) that take a `T`.

[Implicit conversion without assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703555/implicit-conversion-without-assignment)

Comment: @Timwi, are you sure?  `MyClass<T> myClass`, at this point, `myClass.*` will only resolve members on `MyClass<T>`, not on `T`.  You would have to do as arootbeer mentions, and do `((T)myClass).*` in order to access any members on `T` itself.

Comment: I asked this very question just a few days ago.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703555/implicit-conversion-without-assignment

Comment: @Kirk: I know. *That* is true. But the statement in this answer is still wrong. You can use a `MyClass<T>` in a method call that expects a `T` parameter, for example. Or in a binary operator such as the example in the question. Or in a `return` or `yield return` statement. Or or or ...

Comment: @Timwi - I've edited my statement to address your concerns with its correctness.

Comment: @Timwi, sure, arootbeer would have been better off phrasing it as, "you have to either explicitly cast it to `T` or use it where `T` is inferred, such as a variable or parameter of type `T`."

Comment: @arootbeet - You are correct, if the implicit operator does not run then you get the MyClass type, not T. This is not a problem for me, as in my actual impimentation the wrapper type exposes T as well as several additional related properties.

Comment: I know that this question is quite old, but what about the situation for example where you define a class `SerializedKeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` and you want to be able to implicity convert it to and from `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`?

Comment: @RWolfe if I understand your question correctly, the answer should be exactly the same. There are [certain places the compiler will do that for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710659/182654) and other than those you will have to either explicitly cast to `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` or explicitly type the variable as `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`.