# Type parameter conversion between IEntity<T> and IComparable<T>

Tags: c#

I implemented an abstract `CustomUser` class for customizing Asp.Net Identity as follows:

```
public abstract class CustomUser<TKey, TContext> : IUser<TKey>, IEntity<TKey>
    where TKey : struct, IComparable<TKey>, IEquatable<TKey>
    where TContext : DataContextBase
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(CustomUserManager<CustomUser<TKey, TContext>, TKey, TContext> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
```

where `IEntity` is:

```
public interface IEntity<T>
    where T : IComparable
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

and **IComparable** is:

```
public interface IComparable<in T>
{
    int CompareTo(T other);
}
```

and `IEquatable<T>` is (required by `UserManager`):

```
public interface IEquatable<T>
{
    bool Equals(T other);
}
```

But I am receiving the following error:

> The type `'TKey'` cannot be used as type parameter `'TKey'` in the generic
>   type or method `'XXX.CustomUserManager<TUser,TKey,TContext>'`. There is
>   no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from `'TKey'` to
>   `'System.IEquatable<TKey>'`.

`TKey` inherits `IComparable` and `IEquatable` as I receive more errors otherwise. Could you please explain why this conflict occurs?

Comment: Does your `CustomUserManager` inherit `UserManager<TUser, TKey>` ? If so, you can see in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290(v=vs.108).aspx) that `TKey: class, Object, IEquatable<TKey>`, whereas you defined `TKey: struct,....`.

Comment: @Michael This is strange. Because when I navigate to UserManager, I see that TKey : System.IEquatable<TKey>

Comment: please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823145/implicit-operator-on-generic-types

Comment: @yackovmandeszaig I don't see how this relates to my question. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Why is `IEntity` constraining its key to the non generic `IComparable`?

Answer (score 0):

i spuspect that it should be some implicit operator but there is no way to cast between those 2 interfaces

```
public static implicit operator IEquatable<T> (IComparable<T> obj)
{
    return ???;
}
```

maybe you can try extends **IEntity** to implement IEquatable as well

public interface IEntity where T : IComparable, IEquatable